# how convert the following curl command to request node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, openstack, object-storage

**Following is the curl command and i want to convert it into request of node js**

```
curl -X PUT -H "X-Auth-Token: 6c82631a825d466fb8fb1cb61ecfbb99" -T wings-logo.png http://iecos.enlightcloud.com:8080/v1/
AUTH_9094738624f340d1ae02070cdc4b286d/test1/
```

Comment: What is this ? A complete curl command ?

Comment: @MalavanRockzz some of the command was hidden because the code block was incorrectly formatted. The full command is now visible.

Comment: Sure. https://onlinedevtools.in/curl use this tool to convert curl to nodejs request

Comment: Your question is too broad. What HTTP request library are you using? What have you tried so far? etc etc

Answer (score 0):

this could be your nodeJS request,
You can try,
Geneartion using `https://curl.trillworks.com/#node`

```
var request = require('request');

var headers = {
    'X-Auth-Token': '6c82631a825d466fb8fb1cb61ecfbb99',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};

var dataString = '@/path/wings-logo.png';


var options = {
    url: 'http://xxxx:8080/v1/
AUTH_9094738624f340d1ae02070cdc4b286d/test1/',
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Comment: Seems like getting it from here-> https://onlinedevtools.in/curl

Comment: You are forgetting to add the file here. wings-logo.png ?

Comment: I want with file upload